# knockoutjs to get input values and pass the values to another array name while clicking the button

Tags: knockout.js

My request is, on-click on a button how to get the value of the input field(id="inputCustomViewName") and use it to name the view?

HTML:

```
    <div class="rowStyle01">
                        <label>Define a new custom view</label>
                        <div class="inputStyle03">
                            <input type="text" id="inputCustomViewName" placeholder="Enter a name for your customer view" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="buttonStyle03 buttonStyle03Ext01 columnRight" data-bind="click: myParentViewModel.addNewCustomView">
            <a>Save</a>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function ParentViewModel()
{
    var that = this;
    that.myViewModelRibbon = new TabViewModel();

    that.addNewCustomView = function (data, event) {
        var allSubTAbs = data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs();
        var newSubTab = {
            "SubTabName": "sample text", // how to get this name from text box ?
            "IconPath": "images/icons/Document.png",
            "GroupID": "0",
            "IsMultipleActive": "0",
            "EnabledState": "enabled",
            "CallbackOnSelect": "openCommonForm"
        };
        data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs.push(newSubTab);

    }
    return that;
}

var myParentViewModel = new ParentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myParentViewModel);
```

Now when i click on the "Save" button only the  "SubTabName": "sample text" is pushing every time on myViewModelRibbon, whereas i want the input value, whatever we typed in that it should push to the view model... how ? any soln ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field to the ParentViewModel and bind it to the input box.
Whenever the input value changes, the binded field will be updated. This is exactly where knockout should be used.

```
...
<input type="text" id="inputCustomViewName" 
       placeholder="Enter a name for your customer view"
       data-bind="value: myParentViewModel.tabName" /> 
...


function ParentViewModel()
{
    var that = this;
    that.tabName = ko.observable(); // <- new field (observable)
    that.myViewModelRibbon = new TabViewModel();

    that.addNewCustomView = function (data, event) {
        if (that.tabName() != null && that.tabName() !== '') { 
            var allSubTAbs = data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs();
            var newSubTab = {
                "SubTabName": that.tabName(), // <--
                "IconPath": "images/icons/Document.png",
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: excellent!!!! thanks you sooo much... it get added perfectly... but still i have question? Suppose if the value is null it should not work... ..i.e now tab should be added... how to do that?

Comment: Well, you check for its value (not equal to null or empty string I suppose also) before adding the tab --> `if(that.tabName() != null && that.tabName() !== '')` that encapsulates the code to execute.

Comment: I tried like below: now is not working!!...    if (that.tabName() != null && that.tabName() !== '') {
        that.addNewCustomView = function (data, event) {
            var allSubTAbs = data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs();
            var newSubTab = {
                "SubTabName": that.newCustomViewSubTab(), // getting the SubTabName from the input observables text box
                "IconPath": "images/icons/Document.png",
                "GroupID": "0",
      

        }
        return that;
    }

Comment: It's `addNewCustomView` that should check for null before adding a new tab. The `if` should be inside it (take a look at my edit). I recommend that you take the time to learn a little bit more the basics of javascript so that you don't waste time on this kind of mistakes.

Comment: Hey manji thanks to your note... it working only i added the if condition above the "data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs.push(newSubTab);" line...

Comment: I tried both comparison as one like this: :)       if(!!that.tabName()){
        //if (that.newCustomViewSubTab() != null && that.newCustomViewSubTab() !== '') {
            data.myViewModelRibbon.ActiveSubTabs.push(newSubTab);
        };

Comment: Manji: to move further the same functionality.. suppose if added more than 6 tabs. i want to enable the arrow on the last (bcus it should not over flow the view port resolution..on click on the arrow.. we need to show the hidden tab which is added... any idea? got it ?

Comment: The `if` should go before the creation of the new tab, otherwise you will create it for nothing if tabname is null. For the other functionality, I suggest that you ask a new question, because it's not related to this and will not be clear answering in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61492/discussion-between-krish-and-manji).

Comment: All: To move further the same functionality.. suppose if added more than 6 tabs. i want to enable the arrow on the last (bcus it should not over flow the view port resolution..on click on the arrow.. we need to show the hidden tab which is added... any idea? got it ?